# If statement with multiple conditions malfunction

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

I'm attempting to validate an HTML form via jQuery. However, the second condition (namely that the value of the text field must a certain number) does not seem to work. If anyone can show why, that would be great. Thank you.

I've attached the code to this question.

```js
$("#sample1").keyup(function (e) {
 var s_id = $('#sample1').val();

    if (e.keyCode == 13 || s_id=="220764690") {
        alert('Captured Enter !')
        // Do whatever you need
    }
});
```

```css
h1{
 text-align:center;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;

}

.sample1{
 text-align: center;
}

.insert {
  display: inline-block;
}

.log{
 background-color:lightblue;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:90px;
  vertical-align: middle;

}

.logo{
  display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.amber-pink.min.css" />
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<center><div class = "log">
<h1>Hey Technite!</h1>
<center>
<form action="#">
  <div class="insert mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield textfield-demo">
  
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1" id= "atext">Student ID</label>
  </div>
 </form>
 </center>
 </div>
 </center>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<img src = "https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-00f778bc5f5fcb5d79a0372986ab1e66.webp" class = "logo">
```

Comment: the alert shows when i run your code snippet and enter 220764690 as Student ID

Comment: Right, however, it does no without the press of the enter key.

Comment: @DiViHart you want to alert without enter key?

Comment: Right now, it displays the alert as soon as I finish typing 220764690. However, I want to press enter to activate the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `&&` operator instead of `||`. So you can get both condition if it is true.

```
$("#sample1").keyup(function (e) {
    var s_id = $('#sample1').val();

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && s_id=="220764690") {
        alert('Captured Enter !')
        // Do whatever you need
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't aware of the fine distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You have little mistake on your `if` condition, instead of `||` you need to use `&&` in order to check user has enter `enter` key and 220764690 on `input`.

```js
$("#sample1").keyup(function (e) {
 var s_id = $('#sample1').val();

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && s_id=="220764690") {
        alert('Captured Enter !')
        // Do whatever you need
    }
});
```

```css
h1{
 text-align:center;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;

}

.sample1{
 text-align: center;
}

.insert {
  display: inline-block;
}

.log{
 background-color:lightblue;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:90px;
  vertical-align: middle;

}

.logo{
  display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.amber-pink.min.css" />
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<center><div class = "log">
<h1>Hey Technite!</h1>
<center>
<form action="#">
  <div class="insert mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield textfield-demo">
  
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1" id= "atext">Student ID</label>
  </div>
 </form>
 </center>
 </div>
 </center>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<img src = "https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-00f778bc5f5fcb5d79a0372986ab1e66.webp" class = "logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the alert shows when you have that ID then press enter,you need to use && operator, not ||